# Thunderbird draft gets saved automatically as text

Tags: email, formatting, attachment, thunderbird

In Word (or Excel) when I save and send the currently open file to my Email client (Thunderbird) a normal Email window gets opened and the file has been attached. Additionally an image containing my contact data is attached as my signature automatically and correctly. I can add text and change its format. So far the contents are in HTML.

Then I save a draft (I don't send out the Email!) and close the Email window. Later when I open that draft, the attached file (Word or Excel file) is still attached BUT my signature (the image file) is gone. The Email text looks like plain text content.

I am using Thunderbird 45.8.0 (the most current version) and Windows 7 Professional.

Appreciate any hints and ideas that could help!

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a bug in Thunderbird.